# Docusaurus: Getting Error: Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas

Tags: docusaurus

When I do a `npm run start` I get the following:

```
npm run start                                                                                      



> my-website@0.0.0 start

> docusaurus start



[INFO] Starting the development server...

[ERROR] Error: Cannot mix different versions of joi schemas

    at new module.exports (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/error.js:23:19)

    at module.exports (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/@hapi/hoek/lib/assert.js:21:11)

    at Object.exports.isSchema (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/common.js:132:5)

    at Object.internals.schema (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/compile.js:66:16)

    at Object.exports.schema (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/compile.js:17:26)

    at internals.Base.$_compile (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/base.js:646:24)

    at /Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/types/keys.js:260:92

    at Object.exports.tryWithPath (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/common.js:176:16)

    at internals.Base.method [as keys] (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/types/keys.js:260:32)

    at internals.Base.method [as append] (/Users/russurquhart_boomi/node_modules/joi/lib/types/keys.js:189:29)

[INFO] Docusaurus version: 2.1.0

Node version: v16.17.0
```

Here is my docusaurus.config.js file:

```
// @ts-check
// Note: type annotations allow type checking and IDEs autocompletion

const lightCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/github');
const darkCodeTheme = require('prism-react-renderer/themes/dracula');

/** @type {import('@docusaurus/types').Config} */
const config = {
  title: 'Boomi Docusaurus POC',
  url: 'https://your-docusaurus-test-site.com',
  baseUrl: '/',
  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',

  // GitHub pages deployment config.
  // If you aren't using GitHub pages, you don't need these.
  organizationName: 'facebook', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'docusaurus', // Usually your repo name.

  // Even if you don't use internalization, you can use this field to set useful
  // metadata like html lang. For example, if your site is Chinese, you may want
  // to replace "en" with "zh-Hans".
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en'],
  },

  presets: [
    [
      'classic',
      /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').Options} */
      ({
        docs: {
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          // Please change this to your repo.
          // Remove this to remove the "edit this page" links.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/main/packages/create-docusaurus/templates/shared/',
        },
        blog: {
          showReadingTime: true,
          // Please change this to your repo.
          // Remove this to remove the "edit this page" links.
          editUrl:
            'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/tree/main/packages/create-docusaurus/templates/shared/',
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      }),
    ],
  ],

  themeConfig:
    /** @type {import('@docusaurus/preset-classic').ThemeConfig} */
    ({
      navbar: {
        title: 'Boomi Atmosphere',
        logo: {
          alt: 'Boomi Doc Site',
          src: 'img/logo.svg',
        },
        items: [
          {
            type: 'doc',
            docId: 'intro',
            position: 'left',
            label: 'Tutorial',
          },
        ],
      },
      footer: {
        style: 'dark',
        links: [
          {
            title: 'Docs',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Atmosphere Documentation',
                to: '/docs/intro',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'Community',
            items: [
              {
                label: 'Stack Overflow',
                href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Discord',
                href: 'https://discordapp.com/invite/docusaurus',
              },
              {
                label: 'Twitter',
                href: 'https://twitter.com/docusaurus',
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            title: 'More',
            items: [
            ],
          },
        ],
        copyright: `Copyright © ${new Date().getFullYear()} Docusaurus POC - Built with Docusaurus.`,
      },
      prism: {
        theme: lightCodeTheme,
        darkTheme: darkCodeTheme,
      },
    }),
  themes: [
    [
      "@easyops-cn/docusaurus-search-local",
      /** @type {import("@easyops-cn/docusaurus-search-local").PluginOptions} */
      ({
        hashed: true,
        language: ["en", "zh"],
        highlightSearchTermsOnTargetPage: true,
        explicitSearchResultPath: true,
      }),
    ],
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

I got the errors after I added the `docusearch-search-local` plugin.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I had NOT installed the `docusaurus-search-local` item in the directory with my docusaurus files, instead I had installed it in `~/`. Once I deleted it from this location, and then put it into the correct location, no problems!